# Get Lua Stdout, from C API

Tags: c, lua

I am strugling to get stdout from a lua Script frontend, in the C banckend:

> type(_ENV.io.stdout)
>   userdata

From C, I am doing:

```
lua_getglobal(L,"_G");
lua_pushstring( L, "io" );
lua_gettable( L, -2 );
lua_pushstring( L, "stdout" );
lua_gettable( L, -2 );
stackTrace( L );
```

So at this point I get:

```
---- Begin Stack ----
Stack size: 3

3 -- (-1) ---- userdata
2 -- (-2) ---- table
1 -- (-3) ---- table
---- End S tack ----
```

Does any one knows How to get stdout, stderr, so that I can printf() for it, from Lua C API?

Comment: What exactly is your question? What do you mean by "get stdout" from Lua? Lua and C can both output to stdout. There is not a different stdout for Lua vs C.

Comment: My Aplication is started by a lua Script, and its stdout if conected to systemd log system...when I do "require" for my library, the printfs inside library doesn't go to systemd...because they have not the same stdout FILE *...

Comment: You mean that your Lua script launches a separate process?

Comment: I include( "require" ) my library, then I printf inside functions of my library, but the return sadly doesn't go to Lua frontend, so I need to figure out a way, and it seems that Maybe _G.io.stdout should be a metatable,w were maybe would be the File descriptor that Lua is using..

Comment: `root@rockpro64:~# ps -L -F -p 311
UID        PID  PPID   LWP  C NLWP    SZ   RSS PSR STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root       311     1   311  0    1   866  1536   4 04:27 ?        00:00:00 lua /usr/local/sbin/ats` its the same process, only one process is launched..

Comment: Thanks for your help!
**Henri Menke** already provided a solution, but my initial problem, turns out to be somewere in SystemD..since it get stderr, and not stdout..

Answer (score 2):

You can get the underlying file handle using the Lua API, but it's definitely not a good idea because this is an implementation detail.  As you can see it changed between Lua 5.2 and 5.1.

```c
#include <lua.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>

int main() {
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    lua_getglobal(L, "io");
    lua_pushstring(L, "stdout");
    lua_gettable(L, -2);
    FILE *lstdout =
#if LUA_VERSION_NUM > 501
        ((luaL_Stream *)lua_touserdata(L, -1))->f;
#else
        *(FILE **)lua_touserdata(L, -1);
#endif
    lua_pop(L, 2);

    fprintf(lstdout, "Hello World!\n");

    lua_close(L);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works OK!!
I suppose that its the same for stderr?!

Unfortunatly for me, I think that SystemD.. is not getting stdout, only stderr..
I will have to figure out how to drive stdout+stderr to SystemD lof system..

Comment: `Thanks a lot, it works OK!!
I suppose that its the same for stderr?!

Unfortunately for me,
I think that SystemD.. is not getting stdout, only stderr..
I will have to figure out how to drive stdout + stderr to SystemD log system..

But from a C perspective, we could need to access this File descriptors, to pass them to some backed dealing with several processes( for example ), so your answer is very valuable.`